# Javascript: Push JSON String as Value of an Input String (Escape/Unescape)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Following Situation (see plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fOJ5zRvqCKvOC3olik8S?p=preview):

[image]

```
<input ng-model="x" type="text">
<button ng-click="add(x)"> push input's value </button>
```

Text-Input has a JSON-String as value (I put it manually)

```
{ "i":3, "j":5 }
```

and I want to transfer its value and push it afterwards in Controller into an array. As you can see I've an escaped version of it in the array, what I want to avoide.

How should my escape/unescape strategy look ? Where should I begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$scope.a.push(JSON.parse(param));
```